# How to override Parent class using new object?

Tags: java

I am trying to generate custom XML message via class ParentMessage, I don't 
know how to override the fields and the methods.

For this issue there is 3 class.

1 -   **ParentMessage** (source code core), I don't have access to code.

2 -  **ChildMessage**(My class core),  I need to **override** ParentMessage class by creating **new object** of ParentMessage.

3 – **Main**(client class), use fields and methods of  ChildMessage.

Thanks for any help.

```
abstract class ParentMessage extends Packet {
    // this is source code, current fields library , I can't Change the method or have access to these fields.
    public String element  =  "message"; 
    public String type       =  "email";    
    public String body      =  ""; 
    public String phone    =  ""; 
    public String from      =  "";
    public String to          =  "";


    pubilc void sendMessage(String element, String type, String body){
        // this current method library , I can't Change the method
        //build xml format
        //send message

        //example of format XML message
        //<message to='rotem@example.com/LIB'>
        //      <from>bob@example.com/LIB</from>
        //      <type>email</type>
        //      <body>some text body</body>
        //</message>
    }
}
```

//

```
abstract class ChildMessage {
        // this my class I want to override the ParentMessage Fields and methods 
        // and make here the change code.

        //example of custom XML message

    public String element       =  "rootmessage";    //override the field
    public String element2       =  "element2";          //I add new field       
    public String element3     =  "element3";           //I add new field       
    public String type            =  "web";                 //override the field
    public String body2          =   "body2";            //I add new field       
    public String body3          =   "body3";             //I add new field       

    public ParentMessage parentMessage = new ParentMessage();

    pubilc void sendMessage(String type, String body, String body2, String body3){

            //<rootmessage to='rotem@example.com/LIB'>
        //      <from>bob@example.com/LIB</from>
        //      <type>web</type>
        //      <body>some text body</body>
        //      <element2>
        //          <body2>some text body2</body2>
        //      </element2>
        //      <element3>
        //          <body3>some text body3</body3>
        //      </element3>
        //</rootmessage>

        //send message
    }
}
```

//

```
public class Main {

    // client class
    public String from           =  "bob@example.com/LIB";
    public String to             =  "rotem@example.com/LIB";
    public String type            =  "android";
    public String body           =  "some text body"; 
    public String body2          =   "some text body2";
    public String body3          =   "some text body3";

    public static void main( String ... args ) {

        public ChildMessage childMessage = new ChildMessage();
        childMessage.sendMessage (type, body, body2, body3){};
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to overload the exact same method. That is `pubilc void sendMessage(String element, String type, String body)` and not `pubilc void sendMessage(String type, String body, String body2, String body3)`. Also i don't know if that will solve your issue as you want to create an object of parent class and sill use another method. `I need to override ParentMessage class by creating new object of ParentMessage.`

Comment: You said you want to overide but `ChildMessage` does not extends `ParentMessage`. It is no clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: by creating new object like `public ParentMessage parentMessage = new ParentMessage();` I want to override the ParentMessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to override methods of a class, your class must extend that class :

```
abstract class ChildMessage extends ParentMessage
```

Second of all, fields cannot be overridden. Only methods can.

Comment: So how I can be able to change the value of the elment fields?  `public String element  =  "message"; `

Comment: @miniKID If `element` is public, you can change it from anywhere, though it is better practice to change it via a setter method. Is there no setMessage method in the ParentMessage class?

Answer (score -1):

a very simple example for you:

```
public abstract class Test1 {
    public String element  =  "message0"; 
    public String element1  =  "message1";
}

public class Test2 extends Test1{
    public String element  =  "message2"; 

    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println(element);
        System.out.println(element1);
    }
}
```

You will see it will print:
message2
message1

Do let me know if it is still not clear

Answer (score -2):

To override a method, you need to have the exact same signature.

This:

```
public void sendMessage(String type, String body, String body2, String body3);
```

Does not override this:

```
public void sendMessage(String element, String type, String body);
```

because the former accepts 4 parameters and the latter only accepts 3. If you want to override the method, you have to remove the last parameter so that both accept 3 strings.

(However, since you're adding new arguments to the function, chances are you aren't really overriding it and are rather changing the behaviour altogether. Unfortunately I cannot really help you there because I do not know exactly what you are doing)